# Convention for taking lambda as parameter

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm writing a C++ application and have abstracted a method over a lambda parameter.  I originally used the following signature:

```
void atomically(void (*block)(T& value, bool& retry))
```

But I discovered that you cannot pass an arbitrary lambda as a function pointer -- the lambda must have no captures.  I could use

```
void atomically(const std::function<void (T&, bool&)>& block)
```

Except it is very important in this part of the code that we avoid allocating on the heap, and creating an `std::function` might allocate. (Are there guarantees about if/when it does?)

Finally, I could use:

```
template<class F>
void atomically(const F& block) {
    // use block() as if it had been declared as above
}
```

Except I find this unacceptable as it allows `block` to take its parameters by value instead of by reference, which would be an easy mistake to make and very subtle to debug.

What is the proper convention for taking a lambda as a parameter?  Or, is there a way, in the final template solution, to ensure that `block` gets its parameters by reference?

Comment: You might SFINAE with a *"function"* type traits.

Comment: @Jarod42 first I've heard of SFINAE.  Seems like the right idea but I can't tell how to apply it here; give me a hint?

Comment: To avoid heap allocating, I'd have a (templated) function, create an instance of it and pass a pointer to it. I mean, the function is part of the executable file, not created at runtime.

Comment: You need some function_traits (as the one from [understanding-how-the-function-traits-template-works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283919/understanding-how-the-function-traits-template-works-in-particular-what-is-the)), then, an `std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T&, function_traits<F>::arg<0> && std::is_same_v<bool&, function_traits<F>::arg<1>, int> = 0` should do the job.

Comment: Alternatively, you might use some *`function_view`* as the one from [vittorioromeo](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html)

Comment: Why is it so important for `block` to not make copies of its arguments? Do you realize that you cannot actually enforce that? As, even if it takes its arguments by reference, it may still copy them at some point.

Comment: *Except I find this unacceptable as it allows block to take its parameters by value instead of by reference* What do you mean?

Comment: @Brian: OP isn't against copy but memory allocation (and `std::function` might do, it is suggested but not required by standard to avoid allocation for "small" objects).

Comment: @Acorn, I am against by-value because the idea is that this block is supposed to mutate `value` and `retry`, and if they ended up being copies instead the transaction would just sit there doing nothing forever.  If you got the signature wrong, it should be an error, not a silent bug.

Comment: @Acorn: OP wants to forbid: `atomically([](T t, bool b){/**/})` and forces to have `atomically([](T& t, bool& b){/**/})`.

Comment: @luqui: Notice that the variant with `void atomically(const std::function<void (T&, bool&)>& block)` doesn't enforce that neither.

Comment: @Jarod42, ouch, I hadn't noticed that.  I guess it makes sense with subtyping, since it's legal to pass a `T&` wherever a `T` is expected.

Comment: @Jarod42 In the second to last paragraph, OP said they wanted to make sure that `block` takes its parameters by reference instead of by value.

Comment: @Brian: OP wants to enforce output parameters, that requires non const reference or non const pointer, passing by value doesn't allow modification.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe is a silly way but... if you can use C++17... you can try using `std::function` deduction guides

I mean... you can prepare a custom type trait to check if a `std::function` is of the requested type

```
template <typename>
struct checkFunc : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename T>
struct checkFunc<std::function<void(T&, bool&)>> : public std::true_type
 { };
```

Now, converting the lambda `L` type to the corresponding `std::function` type (`F`) using `std::function` deduction guides, you can use your custom type traits to SFINAE enable/disable the function

```
template <typename L,
          typename F = decltype(std::function{std::declval<L>()})>
std::enable_if_t<checkFunc<F>::value> atomically (L const & bl)
 { /* do something with bl */ }
```

You can verify that

```
auto l1 = [](int &, bool &){};

atomically(l1);
```

compile, because the type of `l1` generate the type `F` as `std::function<void(int &, bool &)>` that matches the `checkFunc` specialization, so `atomically(l1)` is enabled, and that

```
auto l2 = [](int, bool &){};

atomically(l2);
```

doesn't compile, because the type of `l2` generate the type `F` as `std::function<void(int, bool &)>` that doesn't match the `checkFunc` specialization, so `atomically(l2)` isn't enabled.

A possible alternative `atomically()` form, maybe a little less readable but with the advantage that the second template parameter can't be explicated, is the following

```
template <typename L>
std::enable_if_t<checkFunc<decltype(std::function{std::declval<L>()})>::value> 
      atomically (L const & bl)
 { }
```

Observe that, in both cases, the `std::function` is used, compile time, to decide if enable or not `atomically()` but no `std::function` object is created run-time: the lambda remain lambda and run as lambda.

Comment: Instead of CTAD of C++17, you might check if `std::function<void(T&, bool&)>(bl)` is well formed (C++14) (so `template <typename F> using check_type = std::is_constructible<std::function<void(T&, bool&)>, F>`).

Comment: @Jarod42 - I've tried something similar (through `decltype()`) but without success... I'll try with `std::is_constructible`

Comment: @Jarod42 - Failed: I get `true` for `std::is_constructible<std::function<void(int&, bool&)>, decltype(l2)>::value` where `l2` is `[](int, bool &){};` (so unacceptable, according the OP requirements).

Comment: Yes, it is indeed well formed :-/

Answer (score 2):

You might want some `function_view` (taken from [vittorioromeo](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html#fn_view_impl)) (and as its name suggest, no ownership, so don't store it):

```
template <typename TSignature>
class function_view;

template <typename TReturn, typename... TArgs>
class function_view<TReturn(TArgs...)> final
{
private:
    using signature_type = TReturn(void*, TArgs...);

    void* _ptr;
    TReturn (*_erased_fn)(void*, TArgs...);

public:
    template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<
                              std::is_callable<T&(TArgs...)>{} &&
                              !std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, function_view>{}>>
    function_view(T&& x) noexcept : _ptr{(void*)std::addressof(x)}
    {
        _erased_fn = [](void* ptr, TArgs... xs) -> TReturn {
            return (*reinterpret_cast<std::add_pointer_t<T>>(ptr))(
                std::forward<TArgs>(xs)...);
        };
    }

    decltype(auto) operator()(TArgs... xs) const
        noexcept(noexcept(_erased_fn(_ptr, std::forward<TArgs>(xs)...)))
    {
        return _erased_fn(_ptr, std::forward<TArgs>(xs)...);
    }
};
```

Then you might use:

```
void atomically(const function_view<void (T&, bool&)>& block)
```

Comment: Doesn't really handle your signature contraints as `void foo(bool)` is compatible with `function_view<void(bool&)>` (and `std::function<void(bool&)>`)

Comment: True it doesn't exactly handle my constraints but it's quite handy to know about in any case, thank you

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, `T&` is a subtype of `T`, so you have to be more clever, but not terribly. We can explicitly require the things we want and forbid the things we don't:

```
template<class F>
void atomically(const F& block)
{
    static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<const F&, T&, bool&>, "wrong signature");
    static_assert(!std::is_invocable_v<const F&, T&&, bool&>, "need to mutate value");
    static_assert(!std::is_invocable_v<const F&, T&, bool&&>, "need to mutate retry");
}
```

see: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Fc3MBe)

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't call lambda as a parameter, they will produce the values - while your function **atomically** in this case - expecting a function as a parameter, probably you can use std:function to describe the function prototype, as it mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602824/passing-lambda-function-as-parameter-c), you can use something like :

```
template <typename T>
using block = std::function<void(T&, bool&)>;
```

to avoid using passing the pointer and be able to pass by reference.

Comment: I don't understand this at all.  I want to avoid `std::function` because it allocates on the heap––I don't see how renaming it to `block` helps.

Comment: I think this answer is the result of misreading the question. Sucks, but it happens.

Comment: @luqui
yes, as it mentioned in the rude comment under your comment, i misread this point, sorry for this.

Comment: No rudeness was intended. My apologies for offending you.